# SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, scala, hibernate

I have SQL table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user(
   id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

now, how can I make an entry in `user` table using hibernate `JpaRepository` 
my entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class GoldUser {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     @BeanProperty
     var userId: Long = _
}

   object GoldUser {
      def apply: GoldUser = new GoldUser()

      def apply(userId: Long): GoldUser = {
         val user = new GoldUser
         user.userId = userId
         user
      }
   }
```

repository:

```
@Repository
trait UserRoleRepo extends JpaRepository[GoldUser, Long]{

}
```

now whenever I try to insert data like:

```
    val goldUser = GoldUser(10)
    goldUserRepo.save(goldUser)
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

how can I make an entry in the table?

Comment: For those who are not so Scaly-savy, you might want to also explain what `var userId: Long = _` means.

Comment: it is just a simple variable in scala for column id

Comment: Teh field definition in SQL query `id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE` contradicts with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Comment: @Akina then what it should be?

Comment: @Rohan I think (not sure - check the relation between AUTO_INCREMENT and GenerationType.IDENTITY) you need `CREATE TABLE user(id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);`.

Comment: Perhaps @Akina you should add your comment as answer and get it approved.

Comment: @Akina I cannot make id  AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: If so try to add some default value to the field definition simply, like `CREATE TABLE user(id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT 0);`

Comment: @Akina thank you very much for your help and yes it is working but I don't know is it the correct approach or not I need to ask my senior before changing it. but again thank you.

Comment: If `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` codeline means *generate always* (i.e. this field will never be skipped or assigned with NULL value in INSERT query) then it is safe (because it affects nothing).